# kanban view only shows 40 items?

Tags: odoo, kanban

I have a kanban view for my module, and rather than click on the "Show more (xxx remaining)" I would like the view to just show everything.

Anyone know the code to make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web_kanban module,in static/src/js/kanban.js limit is given as 40. `(this.limit = options.limit || 40;` //Line number 44 ). Please change it to `this.limit = options.limit;`. Try to write a customized module.

Comment: How to set options.limit ? Doesn't `options.limit || 40` mean options.limit or 40 if options.limit is not defined (or can be evaluated as False) ?